# Check open TCP/UDP ports with SNMP

Tags: tcp, udp, snmp, ports

I need to find an OID that can be used with "snmpwalk" that describes which TCP/UDP ports that are open and available on my machine (localhost)

A similar post([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485203/check-ports-with-snmp-net-snmp?answertab=votes#tab-top)) about this was to use:

snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost tcpConnState
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost udpLocalAddress

But as i understand it this only show open connections right now?
Anyhow my lab was corrected wrong for using these ones.

Is there any other OID that can show available TCP/UDP ports?

(I am using terminal in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go!

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost tcpConnLocalPort
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost1.3.6.1.2.1.6.13.1.3

snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost udpLocalPort
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.7.5.1.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I wanted.